# How many points do you get when you kill a player?

Tags: moomoo.io

I get a reward in points when I kill someone. How many points can you get from one kill?

Comment: This seems like a rather easy thing to figure out.  Is it really worth asking, let alone self-answering?

Comment: @Frank yes, it is

Comment: I disagree. This is so easy, it doesn't warrant a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, every kill gives you 100 gold, formerly known as points, no matter what.